# How to replicate this specific SUMIFS example in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have these two tables below in SQL:

```
Plant   Material    Dateadd
123     x           11/01/2019
456     y           01/10/2018
456     z           01/09/2017
123     x           01/10/2018
456     y           01/01/2018
123     z           01/10/2020


Plant   Material    Postingdate Quantity
123     z           03/01/2017  1
123     x           01/01/2018  2
456     y           01/04/2017  1
456     z           21/01/2018  2
456     z           01/01/2018  1
123     x           01/01/2017  2
456     y           11/01/2019  1
456     z           01/07/2018  2
123     x           01/01/2020  1
456     y           01/01/2018  2
```

What I need is to create a new column in the first table that sums the quantity on the second table, but only when:

- table1.plant = table2.plant
- table1.material = table2.material
- table1.dateadd < table2.postingdate

To help I made an excel print that show the equivalent formula (SUMIFS):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFhov.png

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is to create a new column in the first table that sums the quantity on the second table, but only when ...

You can use a correlated subquery to perform the count in the second table; the `where` clause of the subquery defines whe correlation conditions:

```
select 
    t1.*, 
    (   
        select sum(quantity) 
        from table2 t2 
        where 
            t2.plant = t1.plant 
            and t2.material = t1.material
            and t2.postingdate > t1.dateadd
    ) t2_quantity
from table1 t
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on the conditions that you set and aggregate:

```
select t1.plant, t1.material, t1.dateadd,
  sum(t2.quantity) totalquantity
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.plant = t1.plant and t2.material = t1.material and t2.postingdate > t1.dateadd
group by t1.plant, t1.material, t1.dateadd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t1.*, 
ISNULL(( select sum(Quantity) 
         from table2 as t2 
         where 
            t2.plant = t1.plant 
            and t2.material = t1.material
            and t2.postingdate > t1.dateadd ),0) as Quantity 
from table1 as t1
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW6BV.png)